# XML Schema for type that can contain zero or more 'x' elements and zero or one 'y' element anywhere?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want my element, called `subquery` to be able to contain zero or more `insert` elements, and zero or one `subquery` element. These elements can be anywhere. These would be valid `subquery` elements:

```
<subquery>
    <subquery>...</subquery>
</subquery>

<subquery>
    <insert />
    <insert />
</subquery>

<subquery>
    <insert />
    <subquery>...</subquery>
    <insert />
</subquery>

<subquery>
    <subquery>...</subquery>
    <insert />
    <insert />
</subquery>

<subquery>
    <insert />
    <insert />
    <insert />
    <subquery>...</subquery>
</subquery>
```

I've tried many ways but can't get a valid schema to work. When I use `maxOccurs="unbounded"` for `insert`'s type inside an All, Liquid XML Studio tells me `maxOccurs` must be 0 or 1. Can't get it to work as a sequence either.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this model do it?: `insert* (subquery, insert*)?`

```
  <xs:element name="subquery">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element ref="insert" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element ref="subquery"/>
            <xs:element ref="insert" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="subqueries">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="subquery"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="subquery">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="subquery"/>
        <xs:element ref="insert"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="insert">
    <xs:complexType/>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This would be sufficient? (I've added a root-element subqueries.)

Cheers,
Wim

Comment: Wouldn't that allow more than one `subquery` inside a `subquery`?